# Do you call it a Gator <,>?

Tags: imperative-programming

What's the accepted name for "<" and ">"?  I always used "open gator" and "close gator".

Answer (score 0):

These can symbols can be referred to as [less-than](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less-than_sign) (`<`) and [greater-than](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater-than_sign) (`>`) signs, and most people with some math/science knowledge will understand what you mean.